# Can't EXEC Stored Procedure in SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, syntax-error

So To make it clear i made some Stored Procedures and saved them and checked they are all okey.
After that i started Testing them and i keep getting this Error

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'Concrete'.
```

Tried it with different Stored Procedures and Still same Error,
My Code that tried to run very simple here it is

```
EXEC OrgInfoByName('Concrete')
```

And My Stored Procedure Code

```
CREATE PROCEDURE OrgInfoByName
(
@C nvarchar(30)
)
AS
Select * from Organization
where OrgName = @C
```

Thanks

Comment: are you Trying to pass a parameter to the store procedure?

Comment: Try EXEC OrgInfoByName 'Concrete'

Comment: Your question is tagged (now) as mysql, but you seem to be writing T-SQL. Which one are you using? The syntax is quite different.

Comment: I've edited the tags, since this is clearly not a mysql question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how you pass parameters to a stored procedure. Use the syntax below:

```
EXEC OrgInfoByName 'Concrete'
```

Comment: @ace_mccloud yea I am trying to pass a parameter and yea it worked without the brackets thanks

Comment: Can you please mark my answer as correct answer as i replied first? thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
EXEC OrgInfoByName 'Concrete'
```

Try this.